# Traversing an Inputted String and Returning a Specific Amount of Letters Within the String

Tags: c++

I am working on a program that has the user input a letter then a string. Once the string is inputted the program should traverse the string and return the amount of the specific letter within the string. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void countLetters(char letter[]);

/**********************************************************************
* Prompts the user for a line of input (using getline), 
* calls countLetters(), and displays the number of letters.
 ***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
   char letter[256];
   countLetters(letter);
   return 0;
}

/**********************************************************************
* Function to return the number of letters in a string.
 ***********************************************************************/
void countLetters(char Letter[])
{
   char text[] = " ";
   int count = 0;

   cout << "Enter a letter: ";
   cin >> letter;

   cout << "Enter text: ";
   cin >> text;
   cin.getline(text, 256);
   for (int i = (sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0]) - 2); i >=0; i--)
   {
      if(text[i])
      {
         count++;
      }
   cout << "Number of '" << letter << "'s: " << count << endl;
   }
}

/* 
The output should be:
Enter a number: e
Enter a string: Hello, programming is fun
Number of 'e's: 1
*/
```

I have tried researching this and have found no help through this method of counting the amount of letters within the string the user inputs. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `if (text[i] == letter)....`

Comment: `char text[] = " "; cin >> text;` will be undefined behavior for any string entered longer than a single character. Be careful with c-strings. If you're in C++ you'll find everything is much easier with `std::string`

Comment: You are using `sizeof` wrong. This operator returns the size of whatever type is provided in the arguments, not the size of arrays and C-style strings. `std::string`s are much easier to use than C-style strings, and it should be your default when you need to store a string, Consider learning from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539).

Comment: @FeiXiang With arrays, `sizeof` will return the size of the entire array in bytes. So OP is using it correctly here.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You're right, but it shouldn't be used to find the length of C-style strings anyway since that's not equal to the size of the array, which is constant. I should have said the operator does not return the *length* of C-style strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most issues have been pointed out in the comments. Here's a fixed version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void countLetters();

/**********************************************************************
* Prompts the user for a line of input (using getline), 
* calls countLetters(), and displays the number of letters.
 ***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
   // You create an array in the function, don't need one here, too
   // char letter[256];
   countLetters();
   return 0;
}

/**********************************************************************
* Function to return the number of letters in a string.
 ***********************************************************************/
void countLetters()
{
   // Your method creates an array of only 2 bytes
   //char text[] = " ";
   char text[256];
   int count = 0;

   // You forgot to declare letter
   char letter;
   cout << "Enter a letter: ";
   cin >> letter;
   // Reading the char leaves a new line. Consume. cin.ignore is another way
   cin.getline(text, 256);

   cout << "Enter text: ";
   cin.getline(text, 256);

   // Overly complicated
   //for (int i = (sizeof(text) / sizeof(text[0]) - 2); i >=0; i--)
   for (int i = 0; text[i]; i++)
   {
      // Compare to letter
      if (text[i] == letter)
      {
         count++;
      }
      // This needs to be outside the loop
      //cout << "Number of '" << letter << "'s: " << count << endl;
   }
   cout << "Number of '" << letter << "'s: " << count << endl;
}
```

In C++, it's almost always better to use `std::string` instead of raw char arrays, but I'll assume this is an assignment and arrays are required.

Comment: Thank you very much, I now see some of the mistakes I made. I appreciate the assistance.